# What's wrong with my function() in Shell Script! Syntax Token errors near {?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

```
#!/bin/bash

# I get the newest file in Directory

latest_file=$(ls -t | head -n 1)
getAlldoublicate() 

# getting Token syntax error here getAlldoublicate() '{

{
 Alldoublicate=$(tr -s ',' ' ' <latest_file  | awk  '{print $2" "$3" "$4}' | uniq -d) 

# here I try to find dublicate rows in csv

 }
if [[ -s latest_file]] ; then

# here I check if file is emty

getAlldoublicate
else
cat "$latest_file"  | mailx -s "$latest_file is empty" bla..`@bla 
fi
```

Comment: Could you please add your _actual_ code without annotations?

Comment: Use [shellcheck.net](http://shellcheck.net) to diagnose syntax errors in your shell code.

Comment: Could you please format your code and add the error phrases?

Comment: If your actual code is `getAlldoublicate() '{`, then the problem is the stray single quote.  But you haven't posted your code, so it's hard to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is your code.

```
#!/bin/bash

# I get the newest file in Directory
latest_file=$(ls -t | head -n 1)

# getting Token syntax error here
getAlldoublicate()
{
    # here I try to find dublicate rows in csv
    Alldoublicate=$(tr -s ',' ' ' < $1 | awk '{print $2" "$3" "$4}' | uniq -d) 
}


if [[ -s $latest_file ]]; then

# here I check if file is emty
    getAlldoublicate $latest_file
else
    cat $latest_file | mailx -s "$latest_file is empty" bla.. @bla 
fi
```

Three points you need to pay attention:

1. `function` must be defined first before being use.
2. You can pass the `latest_file` as an argument when calling `getAlldoublicate`. Then you could use it by `$1` in the function. (`$0` stands for the function being called itself).
3. It would be better if you read the [How to Format Tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) before asking questions.